# How can I check that PDF was loaded correct?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pdfbox

I'm working with selenium and C#, I did use this code but it doesn't working, the error is "Socket reset"

```
        URL TestURL = new URL(URL);


        BufferedInputStream TestFile = new BufferedInputStream(TestURL.openStream());
        PDFParser TestPDF = new PDFParser(TestFile);
        TestPDF.parse();
        String TestText = new PDFTextStripper().getText(TestPDF.getPDDocument());

        Assert.IsTrue(TestText.Contains("Open the setting.xml, you can see it is like this"));
```

or How can I get the response the server to know if the pdf is there?

Thanks.

Comment: socket reset has nothing to do with PDFBox. Maybe your URL is wrong.

Comment: Also maybe the URL you use requires some cookies or other headers to function as desired.

Comment: Personally, I would just compare the hash of the downloaded PDF with the original.

Comment: @DillonMiller at this time he can't download at all.